# Hidden video URL on video.js

Tags: video.js

I wanna hidden my URL video's hosted on Amazon S3 to prevent people download them.

I saw another strategy (Amazon Bucket Policies) but I think it's too complex for this case.

Is possible hidden that one?
What do you suggest for this problem?

Comment: if you use CORS to disable access from any other domains but yours then you can at least make it harder to download the files.

Comment: Give up lol , whatever you do people will crack your protection if they really want to download the video.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of the video tag in the beginning, you could have a data tag with just an id. You could then reference in this id, compare it in the javascript and inject the appropriate video url. As previously stated, there's no true way to protect it. With my method, people can still use fiddler to see where it's being referenced in. They can also use the browser's dev tools.